# Replace iframe scrollbar with floating scroll similar to iPhone

Tags: jquery, iframe, scroll, floating

Is there a way to replace the iframe scrollbars with a a floating bar similar to the one in iPhone using jQuery or another method?

I'm loading external sites inside the iFrames so I don't have the possibility of changin their page contents.

Comment: Yes. First, you need to hide the iFrame's scroll bars. Then you need to overlay a div on top of it with your custom scroll bar.